# Splitting data by commas within a single cell for multiple cells

Tags: database, pandas, tableau-api

[image: Example of an attribute in a single row]

Hi everyone, so I've had trouble with coming up with a solution for the issue above. As shown, I have a couple of attributes that have comma separated values within those single cells. The main issue here is trying to split them up and yet retain the correct information for the entities.

Currently, a single row represents a single entity. I've tried splitting them up using pandas, specficially through a split and explode function, as shown below.

`df.set_index(['Name', 'Entity Type', ...  'News', 'University',
       'Done Editing!']).apply(lambda x: x.str.split(',').explode()).reset_index()`

I've taken note to exclude the columns that I want to split and retain the ones that I don't. However, this method does not work for mulitple columns, as I get a `ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!`.

The goal here is to be able to split each of these records so that I can ultimately use them in a BI tool such as Tableau to create a dashboard. Would greatly appreciate any suggestions or how I can accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

I have just completed writing a blog post, with python script embedded for download, on completing this via a TabPy server in Tableau Prep. Check it out: https://apogeeintegration.com/blog/apogee-busts-out-multi-value-cells-using-tableau-prep-builder

I think this will be extremely helpful in completing your problem.

-Sara

Comment: Thanks Sara, will definitely check this out.